# Send message from Jquery to apache log

Tags: jquery, apache, logging

I want to know if there's a way to send a message from Jquery to Apache log. I need it because I remove some things and I want to register it into apache log.

Hope to find and answer

Comment: use jquery ajax to call serverside code to write the logs for you.

Comment: I'm using ajax now. When I want to write in my apache log is when the callback function of ajax goes to error. Thnks